# Zipping files with apache camel

Tags: zip, apache-camel

i am saving files on path `C:\Cdr\core\year\month\date\fileName`
and i want to zip all the files created on previous day and before that.I am unable to find a way to provide dynamic file path and file name to file Consumer for zipping files. Even when using      `filename=${beans:utility.generateFileName}`, i am only able to provide file name not the file path.Is there a way to do this using apache Zip file data format.

Comment: If I properly understand your question , you want to zip all the files which are created from yesterday to specific path(is it ftp or local drive) with file name, is that correct? Can you share sample code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the way for same by using filter

```
<routeContext id="zipFileRoute" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
  <route id="zipFile">
    <from uri="file://C:/CdrJson?recursive=true&amp;delete=true&amp;filter=#myFilter/>
    <log message="reading from ${in.header.CamelFileName} and file path is ${file:path}"/>
    <setHeader headerName="CamelFileName">
      <simple>${bean:utility?method=processFileName}</simple>
    </setHeader>
    <marshal>
      <zipFile/>
    </marshal>
    <to uri="file://C:/CdrJson"/>
    <log message="This route finished zipping files"/>
  </route>
</routeContext>
```

Code for myFilter:

```
public class MyFileFilter<T> implements GenericFileFilter<T> {
  public boolean accept(GenericFile<T> file) { 
    // we want all directories
    if (file.isDirectory()) {
      return true;
    }
    Calendar date = new GregorianCalendar();
    String fileName = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(new Date());
    if(file.getFileNameOnly().startsWith(fileName)){
      return false;
    }
    return !file.getFileName().endsWith(".zip");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use *GenericFileFilter* to filter the file based on created date. Using this at run time you can skip the files not matched with desired criteria.

> Ref: http://camel.apache.org/file2

**Dynamic path:** I am not sure about what level of dynamism you are expecting. File consumer is a polling consumer, one that explicitly makes a call when it wants to receive a message. So you can either hard-code the file path or set dynamic path resolved at run time from property file (Ref:Proertyplaceholder) as below,

```
 <from uri="file:{{consumer.file.path}}"/>
```

**To Zip files:** You have to use aggregate pattern as below,

```
from("file:{{consumer.file.path}}")
  .aggregate(new ZipAggregationStrategy())
    .constant(true)
    .completionFromBatchConsumer()
    .eagerCheckCompletion()
  .setHeader(Exchange.FILE_NAME, constant("<DesiredFileName>.zip"))
.to("file:output/directory");
```

Hope it helps!!

Comment: The issue is that i cant give the file path or the file name statically in properties file as it includes date,month and year.And also,if you can guide me how to write above code in spring DSL,it will be helpful.

Comment: File consumer directory path does not support dynamic simple "expression" i.e ${}. So you cant use current date time stamp in the path. But another work around is you can use Consumer template where you can compute the entire url at runtime. Note: ConsumerTemplate is bit costly so let spring handle its lifecycle. Converting java dsl to spring dsl is pretty easy. Pl try

Comment: If you are going to get only single file you can use pollenrich which accept dynamic uri computed at runtime based on current exchange.